# How to add COALESE function in datatable server side script

Tags: php

I am trying to use COALESCE Function in this script on this line but I am getting some error
The error line is

```
array( 'db' => 'COALESCE(`bb`.`net`,`u`.`net`)',   'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'net' ),
```

Rest of the code is perfect
Is there a better way or any other alteration to use COALESCE Function here please help

This is my full code...

```
<?php

$table = 'entry';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`voucherno`', 'dt' => 0, 'field' => 'voucherno' ),
    array( 'db' => '`ud`.`Name`',  'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'Name' ),
    array( 'db' => 'COALESCE(`bb`.`net`,`u`.`net`)',   'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'net' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`cheque_date`',   'dt' => 3, 'field' => 'cheque_date' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`Cheque_no`',   'dt' => 4, 'field' => 'Cheque_no' ),
    array( 'db' => '`uu`.`country_name`',     'dt' => 5, 'field' => 'country_name'),
    array( 'db' => '`uup`.`name`',     'dt' => 6, 'field' => 'name'),
    array( 'db' => '`uur`.`pfms`',   'dt' => 7, 'field' => 'pfms' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`sum`',     'dt' => 8, 'field' => 'sum' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`utr`',     'dt' => 9, 'field' => 'utr' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`entered`',     'dt' => 10, 'field' => 'entered' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`Description`',     'dt' => 11, 'field' => 'Description' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`tds`',     'dt' => 12, 'field' => 'tds' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`cgst1`',     'dt' => 13, 'field' => 'cgst1' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`sgst1`',     'dt' => 14, 'field' => 'sgst1' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`igst_tds`',     'dt' => 15, 'field' => 'igst_tds' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`cess`',     'dt' => 16, 'field' => 'cess' ),
    array( 'db' => '`u`.`deductions`',     'dt' => 17, 'field' => 'deductions' )
    
);

require('config.php');
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => $db_username,
    'pass' => $db_password,
    'db'   => $db_name,
    'host' => $db_host
);


require('ssp.customized.class.php' );

$joinQuery = "FROM `entry` AS `u` 
LEFT JOIN `bulk` AS `bb` ON (`u`.`id` = `bb`.`id`)
JOIN `bank_details` AS `ud` ON (`ud`.`id` = COALESCE(`bb`.`firm_name`,`u`.`name`))
JOIN `country` AS `uu` ON (`uu`.`id` = `u`.`Budget_head`)
JOIN `pfms` AS `uur` ON (`uur`.`id` = `u`.`PFMS_head`)
JOIN `states` AS `uup` ON (`uup`.`id` = `u`.`sub_head_1`)";
//$extraWhere = "`u`.`voucherno` != 0";
//$groupBy = "`u`.`office`";
$having = "`u`.`bank` = '30412797764' and not `u`.`voucherno` =0";

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery,$having)
);
```

Comment: You are getting 'some error'. What error?

Comment: Please tag/edit your question appropriately -  is SSP from https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables ?

Comment: @AD7six sir yes it is from github

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular sir don’t know what the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Answer.....

```
array( 'db' => 'COALESCE(`bb`.`net`,`u`.`net`)',   'dt' => 2, 'field' => 'net', 'as' => 'net' ),
```